# How to Determine Text Cursor Position in Windows

Tags: winapi, ime

What is the best way to determine the screen co-ordinates of the currently active text input cursor?

I need this for an in-line transliteration program so that I can display some suggestions options to the user as the text is entered.

Comment: What is the cursor on?  A RichEdit?  An edit box?  A winform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First attach the thread input to the active application ([`AttachThreadInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Then get the caret's position with [`GetCaretPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The position is in client coordinates, call [`GetFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to have the handle to the window that has the caret, then convert the coordinates to screen coordinates with [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Finally detach the thread input by calling again `AttachThreadInput`.

Comment: Won't work if application don't use windows caret and have it's own caret.