# How to detect a global caret position on screen

Tags: delphi

How to detect the global keyboard caret position on screen (x,y)  ?
The position is being read from background app in any application.

Comment: `Mouse.CursorPos` perhaps?

Comment: Related, [Caret position on webbrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5247039/576719).

Comment: There's no global caret. You want the caret position when another application's window is showing it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087244/how-to-determine-text-cursor-position-in-windows